# Customizing tfs 2015 capacity planning

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to customize capacity planning in TFS2015? I would like to set capacity per iteration for the whole team or every single person. Is there a way to accomplish that without setting capacity per day for each user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

You have to add the same value for each team member at the dart of the iteration.

You should be able to script it.